# Configure saving of preferences on eclipse.org

Tags: eclipse

I was changing some preferences on my Eclipse Neon when a dialog popped up asking me if I wanted to save them on eclipse.org. I clicked no, but afterwards changed my mind.

How can I make this dialog pop up again, or where can I find the setting in the preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the following: **Preferences -> Oomph -> Setup Tasks -> Preference Synchronizer**. Enable **Synchronize with Eclipse.org** and click **Synchronize Now...**